# How can I get the next redirect url from current

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

When I access to https://song.link/https://open.spotify.com/track/03f7xZmt2wHCIDJBFPK8G4?si=f4RrdDqMT52FqF0yJIfzFw that link have a redirect...

I need to get the next link to do the actual webscraping and get those links.

```js
var request = require('request')
var cheerio = require('cheerio')

request('https://song.link/https://open.spotify.com/track/03f7xZmt2wHCIDJBFPK8G4?si=f4RrdDqMT52FqF0yJIfzFw', function(err, resp, html) {
  if (!err){
    const $ = cheerio.load(html)
    console.log(html)
  }
})
```

Ty for your time

Answer (score 0):

You need puppeteer to do that.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const getSecondURL = async firstURL => {

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
    const [page] = await browser.pages()

    await page.goto(firstURL, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0', timeout: 0})
    while(page.url === firstURL) {
        await page.waitFor(100)
    }
    console.log(page.url())

    await browser.close()
}

const url = process.argv.length > 2 ? process.argv[2] : 'https://song.link/https://open.spotify.com/track/03f7xZmt2wHCIDJBFPK8G4?si=f4RrdDqMT52FqF0yJIfzFw'
getSecondURL(url)
```

You can run this script by put the url in the command line argument syntax:

`$ node script.js [urltoprocess]`

Where urltoprocess is the url string in quote strings. For an example:

```
$ node script.js 'https://song.link/https://open.spotify.com/track/03f7xZmt2wHCIDJBFPK8G4?si=f4RrdDqMT52FqF0yJIfzFw'
```

Comment: @Olzkpex then choose it as the right answer, thanks